# ¿Cómo cambiar el orden de una matriz?

Tags: python, lista, matrices, numpy

Estoy creando la siguiente matriz:

```
[[25  6 27 19  0  3],
 [15 28  6 15  0  8],
 [18 21  2 15  0  8]]
```

La matriz es generada a partir de una lista, esta lista:

```
[25, 6, 27, 19, 0, 3, 15, 28, 6, 15, 0, 8, 18, 21, 2, 15, 0, 8]
```

Estoy creado la matriz de la siguiente manera:

```
  import numpy as np   
  matriz_mensaje = np.array(lista_temp).reshape(3,-1)
```

Sin embargo necesito que sea de esta forma:

```
[[25 19 15 15 18 15],
 [6   0 28  0 21  0],
 [27  3  6  8  2  8]]
```

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Para organizar el código que coloques en tu pregunta, puedes ver [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes reordenar la lista original en las filas finales que buscas obtener, mediante un "slice" de la siguiente forma: `[lista_temp[i:len(lista_temp):3] for i in range(3)]`. La magia la hace el tercer argumento no tan habitual de `[]` que indica el `step`.

Por ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np   

lista_temp = [25, 6, 27, 19, 0, 3, 15, 28, 6, 15, 0, 8, 18, 21, 2, 15, 0, 8]

lista_temp = [lista_temp[i:len(lista_temp):3] for i in range(3)]
matriz_mensaje = np.array(lista_temp).reshape(3,-1)
print(matriz_mensaje)

[[25 19 15 15 18 15]
 [ 6  0 28  0 21  0]
 [27  3  6  8  2  8]]
```

Comment: muchas gracias , fue de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0):

puede intentar con esto:

```
from pprint import pprint

array = [25, 6, 27, 19, 0, 3, 15, 28, 6, 15, 0, 8, 18, 21, 2, 15, 0, 8]

#seleccionamos los elementos de 6 en 6
narray = [array[0:6],array[6:12],array[12:]]
pprint(narray)
```

resultado:

```
[[25, 6, 27, 19, 0, 3], [15, 28, 6, 15, 0, 8], [18, 21, 2, 15, 0, 8]]
```

Comment: lo ordena en la misma manera

Comment: ok quieres que el arreglo se vuelve 3 arreglos de string ???

Comment: necesito que siga siendo una matriz pero en esta forma:

Comment: [[25 19 15 15 18 15],
 [6   0 28  0 21  0],
 [27  3  6  8  2  8]]